# Turning Tuple into datetime

Tags: python, datetime, python-requests, tuples

I know this has been asked many times, however, I cannot seem to find one that works for me.

I've got the following text using requests.

```
data = response.text
```

`var racePostTime = ["","2024-01-21 13:00:00","2024-01-21 13:30:00","2024-01-21 14:00:00","2024-01-21 14:30:00","2024-01-21 15:00:00","2024-01-21 15:35:00","2024-01-21 16:05:00","2024-01-21 16:40:00","2024-01-21 17:15:00","2024-01-21 17:50:00"];`

And I've been able to get the data i want using re.

```
posttime = re.findall('(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})', data)  
print(posttime)
```

Getting the below list of tuples.

`[('2024', '01', '21', '13', '00', '00'), ('2024', '01', '21', '13', '30', '00'), ('2024', '01', '21', '14', '00', '00'), ('2024', '01', '21', '14', '30', '00'), ('2024', '01', '21', '15', '00', '00'), ('2024', '01', '21', '15', '35', '00'), ('2024', '01', '21', '16', '05', '00'), ('2024', '01', '21', '16', '40', '00'), ('2024', '01', '21', '17', '15', '00'), ('2024', '01', '21', '17', '50', '00')]`

This is where i'm stuck. I tried the following but got an error.

```
race1 = datetime(posttime[0])
```

Comment: The usual way of turning a string into a datetime object is `datetime.datetime.strptime()`.  There's no need for you to use a regex.

Comment: What is your expected output? As `data` already contains the datetime information, why not just tell python to recognize the format ? Ex: `format_str = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S';
datetime_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(data[1], format_str)` yields `2024-01-21 13:00:00`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like @jasonharper has mentioned, `datetime.datetime.strptime` is more commonly used.

```py
from datetime import datetime
s = '2024-01-21 13:00:00'
print(datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))  # %Y for year in 4 digits
```

So for your case, which you get a JavaScript array, you can simply use `json` library to do the parsing for you.

```py
import json
data = data.split('=')[1][:-1]  # Take the list and eliminate the ';' at the end
arr = json.loads(data)  # Parse string to python list
print(arr)  #  ['', '2024-01-21 13:00:00', ...]
```

Now you get a list of strings of date and time. That's it. Do anything you want with them.

Answer (score 0):

To "unravel" the tuple into individual arguments of a function, use `*` as in

```
from datetime import datetime
race1 = datetime(*posttime[0])
```